# How to link directly to a specific spot in an iFrame?

Tags: iframe, hyperlink

I have a page located at:

`http://localhost:8080/job/demo/865/parsed_console/?`

Inside that page is an `iFrame`:

```
<iframe width="100%" scrolling="auto" height="600" frameborder="0" src="job/demo/865/parsed_console/log.html"></iframe>
```

Within the `iFrame` there are anchor tags which I can browse to with a link like the one below:

`http://localhost:8080/job/demo/865/parsed_console/job/demo/865/parsed_console/log_content.html#ERROR1`

The problem is that if I use the above link I am directed to a page that does not have the outer frame.  **I don't have source control over either page.**

How can I make a link that will go directly to a specific location in the `iFrame` without losing outer frame?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the solution to this is to change the src attribute of the iframe element to include the fragment which you wish to scroll into view. This would be achieved using Javascript.

Comment: Updated my question.  I don't have source control over either page.

Comment: Without source control, this is not possible. If one were to be able to inject controls into a document in such a way, then it would be a massive security problem.

Answer (score 0):

http://localhost/ is only visible from your computer.

```
<iframe name="blah"></iframe>


<a href="http://www.yahoo.com" target="blah">
```

Comment: Yup, but that has nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 0):

In your link add a `target` attribute for example: `<a href="..." target="name_of_iframe"/>` where name_of_iframe the value of the `name` attribute on the `iframe` tag for example: `<iframe name=name_of_iframe"></iframe>`

Comment: Updated question to show the iFrame tag.  What you suggested might work, unfortunately the iFrame does not have a name attribute and I cannot give it one.

Comment: Well, i was going to suggest you add the name attribute dynamically but i now see that you can't change or add code to either page... i guess that leads to a logical conclusion that without being able to make a change... you can't make a change :)

Answer (score 0):

Look for an id tag in the html page at the specific spot you want the iFrame to open at. Then hash tag it in your iFrame

For instance the page you load in your iFrame may have - id="autolog" - or - input id="un"- etc.,

Hash tag the id in your iFrame like so:

```
<iframe src="https://sitethatloadsiniFrame.com#slogin;" frameborder="0" height="98"
width="225" style="float: right; frameborder="0"; SCROLLING=YES></iframe>
```